# Phonegap-Javascript sending cross-domain ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, cross-domain

I'm using PhoneGap and JavaScript to produce an iPhone app. Is it possible to send a cross-domain AJAX (POST) request and download the response as HTML? (ex.: sign into yahoo mail and fetch new mails)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Cordova/PhoneGap allow for [whitelisting](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html) of domains. As long as the server you are requesting is in the whitelist.

Comment: So then it's not possible if the server doesn't accept CORS or JSONP ?

Comment: Actually, the server does not have to support CORS or JSONP in order to make a cross-domain ajax request. The only requirement is to add your domain to the official whitelist inside of your phonegap project(here is the guide) : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: Just a quick note - you need to add `<access origin="..." />`. Don't use uri attribute with PhoneGapBuild.