# Phonegap - Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, cordova, cross-domain

Im creating a mobile app with Phonegap and Backbone.js. My app hits a url which returns an rss feed in xml format and this is to be loaded into the Backbone connection. However I am getting the error:

```
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

In my res/xml/config.xml I have the line:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

The phonegap docs at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html, state that this should stop this type of error, but it's not.

I'm testing from localhost on a desktop browser. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Put his in your top in your PHP file that you make the request to:

> header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

I take it that you use php :)

if now please say which language :)

Comment: Unfortuneately I do not have access to the server.It is a Joomla website though. According to the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920782/phonegap-javascript-sending-cross-domain-ajax-request, I should not need to touch the server...

Comment: If you get this from your browser:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load <some_url> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin... then 100% totally u need to put that code in.

Comment: or...change your page and PHP script to support "JSONP"

Comment: You are trying to access a resource that is not in the same domain as the page from which the script was downloaded, resulting in a "Cross Origin" security error.

Comment: Phonegap got a whitelist aswell, but that dosent have anything to do with the server :)

Comment: I do not have access to the server though. Im using it's rss feed to read latest news from the site. Maybe I need my own server and a proxy php script to go hit the external url, and then return the xml to my client? But I think its possible without this step

Comment: If you dont have access to the server you can make a middle point which will collect the data from the original server.  Thats kinda a funky solution though.  Try and get access to that server that would be the best ;)

Comment: Ah, it works on my mobile device, but not on desktop

Comment: ok then so you havent tested it yet ;)  I hope i was of some help.. please remember to close the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was testing in a browser, the whitelist in res/xml/config.xml only works on a mobile device.