# UI5 and Phonegap

Tags: cordova, sapui5

I am trying to develop an UI5 based application for Android using Phonegap. Therefore I used a demo application that is just adding a simple page. Executing this application on the web server is working, access the index file from local file system is causing:

jquery-mobile-custom.js. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

as cross domain access is forbidden

Using phone gap is showing an empty window. Does phonegap also check for cross domain access and if yes how can this be resolved? Is there a way to show phonegap's js error messages?

Comment: Check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920782/phonegap-javascript-sending-cross-domain-ajax-request
You need to add your URLs to white-list.

Comment: Added * to the whitelist. Now it's working. Thx. Wonder why this is not mentioned in any documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phonegap-Javascript sending cross-domain ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920782/phonegap-javascript-sending-cross-domain-ajax-request)