# Angular http returning error in Phone gap but success in browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, http

I am making an HTTP request in Angular JS.

This works fine in the **browser** and returns the data **successfully**. However, when I test on a device for **Phonegap** usage, it returns an **error**.

The data for the request is passed to a **factory** from a **controller**, below is an example of the code I am using to make the request.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="story in stories" ng-click="setUser(story.name)">
        <img ng-src="{{ story.img }}" width="120" height="108" />
            <div>
                <h2>{{ story.name }}'s Story</h2>
                <p>{{ story.title }}</p>
            </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This HTML calls the function `setUser(story.name)` on `ng-click`, which passes in the current name of the user in the ng-repeat.

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.setUser = function (story) {
    $scope.chosenStory = story;
    dataFactory.setUser($scope.chosenStory); // HTTP call
}
```

The controller above gets the value from the HTML's `ng-click="setUser(story.name)"` and sends it to a `factory` to make the HTTP request.

**FACTORY**

```
setUser : function (val) {
    window.alert(val);
    var username = val;
    window.alert(val);
    $http.get('./js/json/scenarios/' + username + '.json')
        .success(function (data) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(data));
            $location.path('/story');
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {
            window.alert(val);
            window.alert(data);
            window.alert(status);
        });
    },
```

In Google's console it logs the success content from the HTTP request. However, when I test on a device for Phonegap, it always returns the error content of the HTTP request. E.g. it always returns the window.alert from the error function of the HTTP request.

What I am doing wrong / not doing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I face the same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985470/angularjs-ionic-return-404

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99.9% sure this is because of cross domain ajax loading. Try to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin as suggested here [How to enable CORS in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823010/how-to-enable-cors-in-angularjs) or try enabling a whitelist for cross domain of your app as suggest here [Phonegap-Javascript sending cross-domain ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920782/phonegap-javascript-sending-cross-domain-ajax-request)

Ultimately, if nothing works and you control the service, you could try changing the response headers, but it's likely that one of those will make it for you.

Comment: Hi, it's not a CORS problem.