# AngularJS + Ionic return 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, cordova, ionic-framework

I work with ionic and angularJS to build a mobile app.

But I have a problem : HTTP request return 404 in the app **and** on Safari, **but in Google Chrome, the request return correct JSON**.

In the app I have install the `cordova white list plugin`.
I have add `<access origin="*" />` + `<allow-intent href="*"/>` + `<allow-navigation href="*"/>` in the `config.xml`.

**And** `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"><meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
content="default-src *; [...]; script-src http://localhost:35729 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />` in `index.html`.

Here is my code :

```
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 10000
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        alert(JSON.stringify(status));

        // handle success things
        deferred.resolve(data);

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        // handle error things
        alert(JSON.stringify(status));
        alert(JSON.stringify(headers));
        alert(JSON.stringify(config));

        deferred.reject(data);
    });
```

And it return 404. 
What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks you for help me ;)

Comment: Maybe your building your URL wrong, Chrome is pretty forgiving, while other browsers are not. Could you check and add information on the URL parameter in Chrome and Safari/your app.

Comment: Here is the url : `https://example.com/index.php/wc-api/v3/customers/107/orders?consumer_key=ck_XXXX&consumer_secret= cs_XXXX` where `107` is the customer id